# Why this find function return undefined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why this find function return undefined ?

```js
let payload = [{
  test: ''
}];

console.log(payload.find(item => item.test && item.test === '')); // undefined
console.log(payload.find(item => item.test === '')); // {test: ''}
```

if `item.test` is true, I think that it should test whether `item.test` equal to ''.But it is not display like I think.

Comment: `item.test` is an empty string, which is falsy, so `&&` short circuits.

Comment: `''` is not a truthy value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [empty strings are *falsey*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), so the `item.test` conditions fails and excludes the item.

Answer (score 0):

payload.test is an empty string so `if(payload.test)` return false

you can change it to `console.log(payload.find(item => item.test || item.test === ''));`